# What is the best way to include instances and files?

Tags: php

I am working on a php application. I have many classes and files divided into different directories. I have a config file that holds the database connection settings and files with `require`. For example:`require "core/application.php"` and I do this for all my classes and files. `config.php` also creates my objects. I tried to require `config.php` in all my files so that my classes would have access to the objects in `config.php` but it tries to create another object and I get and error saying that the object already exists. I also tried to create an `init()` function and call it in my `index.php` but then I get an error saying that `init()` already exists. I was trying to auto load my classes but I don't think that is going to work. I have been trying different things for the past few days but I cannot figure anything out. I also don't want to pass my classes the objects. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The *best* way is to use namespacing and autoloading.

Comment: Why do you say "but I don't think that is going to work"? Autoloading certainly is the way to go...

Comment: Yeah, agree with above. see this tutorial on autoloading. https://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer or http://torquemag.io/2015/01/using-class-autoloader-improve-wordpress-development/

Comment: @arkascha I don't want to follow psr-0/4 guidelines and use composer. I prefer to write my own code

Comment: @bena Autoloading has nothing to do with composer. It is implemented _by your own coe_, if you chose to implement it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use require_once.

Comment: @arkascha how can you do it without composer?

Comment: @bena Sounds as if you first want to read about what autoloading really is. It has nothing to do with composer. Composer is for installing requirements from remote locations, autoloader is for loading existing classes based on string manipulations and file system logic. http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `require` use `require_once`